# How might I swap the remaining parts of lines (with the exception of first characters) with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a file, `fr.fc` that represents flashcards used by [hardv](https://github.com/dongyx/hardv) that I want to use to generate with `sed` a similar file, `fr-swapped.fc`

```
%% This is a card set for hardv(1)
%% Created at Feb 1, 1997
NEXT    2023-09-10 09:18:28 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 09:18:28 +0200
Q   We should save money.
A   Nous devons économiser de l'argent.
%%
NEXT    2023-09-09 10:51:14 +0200
PREV    2023-09-05 10:51:14 +0200
Q   I should save money.
A   Je dois économiser de l'argent.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q   Demander son chemin in four ways de quatre manières.
A   Pardon, pouvez-vous m'aider ...
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q   I need your help.
A   Je besoin de votre aide.
%%
%%
```

I want to swap questions (that begin with `^Q\t`) with answers (that begin with `^A\t`) without swapping `Q` and `A` themselves so that the result would look like this. For the sake of keeping it simple let us assume that both answers and questions are just of one-line length.
After `NEXT` and `PREV` are tabs as well. Any separators in the middle of the answer or question is a whitespace - table are not allowed here.

```
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q   Je besoin de votre aide.
A   I need your help.
%%
%%
```

I've tried with `sed -n -E '/^Q\t/p; /^A\t/p' fr.fc | sed -E 'N; s/^([QA]{1,1})(.*)\n(.*)/\3\n\2/' >fr-swapped.fc` but to no avail.

Comment: You show one example if `A` that has multiple lines. If `Q`s can also have multiple lines then include one case like that in your example. You should also include common failure cases for such problems like regexp metachars (`,`, `*`, etc.) and backreference metachars (`&`, `\1`, etc.) and common delimiter chars (`/`, etc.) appearing in the text. Also, show ALL of the expected output given your posted sample input, not just some of it, so we have something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Are the spaces after `NEXT` and `PREV` also tabs? Are the spaces at the start of lines in the middle of an answer block like `Excusez-moi je cherche ...` also tabs? Can tabs appear anywhere else in the input or only as that first separator, e.g. `A<tab>foo<tab>bar>`?

Comment: @EdMorton I modified my question with respect to your comment.

Comment: But the only thing you addressed was the multi-line Q/A part (which I assume means that none of the Q or A sections can be multi-line, right?). I had several other suggestions and questions.

Answer (score 3):

The lazy approach would be use `perl` in slurp mode, where the whole input is loaded in `$_` and you can do substitutions on it:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^Q(\t.*\n)A(\t.*\n)/Q$2A$1/mg' your-file
```

If like in an earlier version of your question, the `Q`s and `A`s could be made of several lines continued using TAB-indented lines, it  would be easy to adapt:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^Q(\t.*\n(?:\t.*\n)*)A(\t.*\n(?:\t.*\n)*)/Q$2A$1/mg' your-file
```

---

<sup>BTW, should rather be `We should` -> `Nous devrions`, `I should` -> `Je devrais`, `I need` -> `J'ai besoin de`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Why so complicated? You can use the `N;P;D` pattern with any `sed` to always process two lines at once like this:

```
sed -E 'N;s/^Q(.*)(\nA)(.*)/Q\3\2A\1/;P;D'
```

It does exactly what you describe: Separate a double line into everything after the Q and everything after the A and swaps those parts.

Answer (score 1):

Since all cards are separated by `%%` you could operate on the range `/^Q\t/,/%%/`:

```
sed -E '/^Q\t/,/%%/{H;/^Q\t/h;/%%/!d;x;s/^(Q\t)(.*)(\nA\t)(.*)(\n%%)$/\1\4\3\2\5/;}' infile
```

i.e. accumulate all lines in that range in the hold space (`H`) overwriting it when range starts (`/^Q\t/h`) and then deleting the lines from the pattern space except when range ends (`/%%/!d`) at which point you e`x`change buffers and swap the contents of `Q` and `A` via `s` command.
This should work with multi-line questions and answers.

---

If questions and answers are always one-line-only, you can simplify it and use `N` when you encounter a question so as to get the answer also in the pattern space and then swap them e.g.

```
sed -E '/^Q\t/{N;s/^(Q\t)(.*)(\nA\t)(.*)$/\1\4\3\2/;}' infile
```

or, with minimal regex and without that picket fence, with any `sed`, you could run

```
sed '/^Q /{s//A /;h;d
}
/^A /{s//Q /;G
}' infile
```

that is, change only the initial `Q\t` to `A\t`, save the line in the hold space, delete it from the pattern space then, on the next line, change the initial `A\t` to `Q\t` and append the saved line to the pattern space.
Note that all blanks after the `Q`s and `A`s in the code are actual TAB characters. One inserts them in terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    sub(/^Q\t/,"A\t") {
        question = $0
        next
    }
    sub(/^A\t/,"Q\t") {
        $0 = $0 ORS question
    }
    { print }
' fr.fc
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
%%      This is a card set for hardv(1)
%%      Created at Feb 1, 1997
NEXT    2023-09-10 09:18:28 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 09:18:28 +0200
Q       Nous devons économiser de l'argent.
A       We should save money.
%%
NEXT    2023-09-09 10:51:14 +0200
PREV    2023-09-05 10:51:14 +0200
Q       Je dois économiser de l'argent.
A       I should save money.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q       Pardon, pouvez-vous m'aider ...
A       Demander son chemin in four ways de quatre manières.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q       Je besoin de votre aide.
A       I need your help.
%%
%%
```

Here is the above with sed-like brevity if you favor that over clarity:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^Q\t/,"A\t"){q=$0;next}sub(/^A\t/,"Q\t"){$0=$0ORS q}1' fr.fc
%%      This is a card set for hardv(1)
%%      Created at Feb 1, 1997
NEXT    2023-09-10 09:18:28 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 09:18:28 +0200
Q       Nous devons économiser de l'argent.
A       We should save money.
%%
NEXT    2023-09-09 10:51:14 +0200
PREV    2023-09-05 10:51:14 +0200
Q       Je dois économiser de l'argent.
A       I should save money.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q       Pardon, pouvez-vous m'aider ...
A       Demander son chemin in four ways de quatre manières.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q       Je besoin de votre aide.
A       I need your help.
%%
%%
```

There may be better possible solutions depending on the answers to my question in comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(Q[ \t]+)([^\n]*\n?)(A[ \t]+)([^\n]*\n?)/\1\4\3\2/gwfr-swapped.fc' fr.fc
$ cat fr-swapped.fc
%% This is a card set for hardv(1)
%% Created at Feb 1, 1997
NEXT    2023-09-10 09:18:28 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 09:18:28 +0200
Q   Nous devons économiser de l'argent.
A   We should save money.
%%
NEXT    2023-09-09 10:51:14 +0200
PREV    2023-09-05 10:51:14 +0200
Q   Je dois économiser de l'argent.
A   I should save money.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q   Pardon, pouvez-vous m'aider ...
A   Demander son chemin in four ways de quatre manières.
%%
%%
NEXT    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
PREV    2023-09-08 20:50:03 +0200
Q   Je besoin de votre aide.
A   I need your help.
%%
%%
```